# Bash quеstion (RegExp)

Tags: regex, bash

Why does not work first and second variants, but third works

```
    #!/bin/sh
    #---------------------------------------------

    text="my:?text=this:one"
    if (echo $text | grep '^my\:\?text=this\:one') then
        echo "1"
    elif (echo $text | grep '^my:\?text=this:one') then
        echo "2"
    elif (echo $text | grep 'text=this:one') then
        echo "3"
    fi
```

Comment: There's no need to use `grep`; `bash` can handle regular expressions using the `=~` operator:  `if [[ $text =~ $regex ]]; then ...; fi`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

grep does not use regular expressions by default, add the `-E` flag to enable extended regular expressions.

Edit: grep does not use *extended* regular expressions by default, and `grep -E` is usually aliased to `egrep` for quicker use

Answer (score 3):

Use [Egrep](http://ss64.com/bash/egrep.html) for Extended grep functionality :

```
echo $text | egrep '^my\:\?text=this\:one'
```

Comment: but if you DO use egrep, you will have to escape the `?`

Answer (score 1):

Because `:` is not a special symbol in regex and doesn't need escaping.

Comment: neither is `?` unless you `-E` grep or backslash it.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the backslash before the question mark. It is not considered a special character by `grep`. On the contrary, adding the backslash adds the special meaning to it.